# Use variable in whole controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have an if statement based on entrust roles package, and i want to use the outcome to prefix my return views in laravel. What options do i have?

What i have now:

```
public function __construct() {        
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator')) {
        $route = 'admin';
    } else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('company')) {
        $route = 'company';
    } else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('schoolowner')) {
        $route = 'school';
    }
}

public function index()
{
    return view($route.'.person.index', compact('user'))->with('status', 'No school');
}
```

How can i use the if statement variable inside return view function in a laravel way? Or even use the outcome on all controllers

Should i use middleware? Or just the php way

Or view share in provider?

Comment: Try to create `protected $route;` inside the controller class, then inside `__construct()` at the bottom, write `$this->route = $route`. Would that work? Then, `$this->route` inside any other method should work. Let me know if it works

Comment: This works! Saved a lot of lines since i was using this if statement in every function. Thanks!

Comment: You can even put it in your base controller if you use it in many controllers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create `protected $route;` variable and add to your class
and use it with `$this->route`

```
protected $route;

public function __construct() {        
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('administrator')) {
        $this->route = 'admin';
    } else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('company')) {
        $this->route = 'company';
    } else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('schoolowner')) {
        $this->route = 'school';
    }
}

public function index()
{
    return view($this->route.'.person.index', compact('user'))->with('status', 'No school');
}
```